# How to make this code work on Mesa3d?

Tags: opengl, glsl, mesa

This GLSL code compile and run warningless in ATI's OpenGL:

```
void main()
{
  vec4 tmp = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
  tmp.xyz = tmp.xyz / (1 - tmp.w);
  tmp.w = 1;
  gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * tmp;
  gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
}
```

Why does it fail with mesa? How to decrypt that error message and make it Mesa's implementation compliant?

```
Compilation log:
0:1(88): error: Could not implicitly convert operands to arithmetic operator
0:1(89): error: Operands to arithmetic operators must be numeric
0:1(97): error: type mismatch
```

Comment: I think the 88, 89 and 97 might be character/byte offsets into the shader listing.

Comment: Could you try using `1.0` instead of `1` in both cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your `1`s to `1.0`s.