# GLSL operands to arithmetic operators must be numeric

Tags: opengl, glsl, glad

I have some old GLSL code that compiled fine previously, but after switching to Linux's gcc compiler it's suddenly throwing errors. From the fragement shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;

// texture samplers
uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform vec3 lightColor;

void main()
{
//ambient lighting
vec3 ambLig = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
float ambientStrength = 0.15;
vec4 ambient = ambientStrength * vec4(ambLig,1.0);

//diffuse lighting
vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);  

float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;

//specular lighting
float specularStrength = 0.5;

vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);  

float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), 32.0);
vec3 specular = specularStrength * spec * lightColor;  

FragColor = texture(texture0, TexCoord) * (ambient + diffuse + specular);
}
```

This throws an error on the final line, where I calculate `FragColor`:

```
Using ALSA driver
ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: FRAGMENT
0:37(45): error: vector size mismatch for arithmetic operator
0:37(45): error: operands to arithmetic operators must be numeric
0:37(14): error: operands to arithmetic operators must be numeric
```

I checked out some [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159817/how-to-make-this-code-work-on-mesa3d) and it seems the problem occurs when using GLSL 1.2 or earlier, since it doesn't do automatic casts. But I have no idea what the problem could be here, since I'm using OPENGL Core 3.3, [which should map to GLSL 3.30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021567/finding-supported-glsl-version) Help me please.

Note: I've included a version of `glad` in the build with api specified as `3.3` for convenience. That could be the root of the problem, but I'm not sure, since I believe I build everything correctly.

EDIT: See answer below, also change

```
vec4 ambient = ambientStrength * vec4(ambLig,1.0);
```

to

```
vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * ambLig;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `texture(texture0, TexCoord)` is of type `vec4`. However, `ambient + diffuse + specular` is of type `vec3`.

Change:

<s>`FragColor = texture(texture0, TexCoord) * (ambient + diffuse + specular);`</s>

```c
FragColor = texture(texture0, TexCoord) * vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular, 1.0);
```